# IndexOutOfRangeException only on Mac OS X Standalone

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I'm getting an IndexOutOfRange exception in my game, but only in a standalone build on Mac OS X. It works fine in the Unity editor on both Windows and OSX, and works fine as a standalone on Windows and Android. On OSX however, I get the following exception:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at WorldController.InstantiateChunk (Vector2i pos, .MeshBuildInfo[] meshes) [0x00072] in /Users/sargunster/Code/Unity Projects/block-game/Assets/Scripts/World/Objects/WorldController.cs:226 
  at WorldController.FixedUpdate () [0x00060] in /Users/sargunster/Code/Unity Projects/block-game/Assets/Scripts/World/Objects/WorldController.cs:79
```

Here's the relevant function:

```
void InstantiateChunk(Vector2i pos, MeshBuildInfo[] meshes)
{
    float worldX = pos.x * World.CHUNK_SIZE - .5f;
    float worldZ = pos.z * World.CHUNK_SIZE - .5f;

    // for each chunk in the column
    for (int y = 0; y < World.WORLD_HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        float worldY = y * World.CHUNK_SIZE - .5f;

        // instantiate the chunk
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(worldX, worldY, worldZ);
        string name = System.String.Format(" Chunk at ({0}, {1}, {2})", pos.x, y, pos.z);

        // THIS IS WHERE IT HAPPENED
        ChunkRenderer opaque = MakeChunk(position, "Opaque" + name, meshes[y].opaque, opaqueMaterial);

        ChunkRenderer transparent = MakeChunk(position, "Transparent" + name, meshes[y].transparent, transparentMaterial);
        Vector3i chunkPos = new Vector3i(pos.x, y, pos.z);
        opaqueInstances.Add(chunkPos, opaque);
        transparentInstances.Add(chunkPos, transparent);
    }
}
```

I followed the references to find where `meshes` was instantiated, and it should have a length of `WORLD_HEIGHT`.

```
MeshBuildInfo[] meshes = new MeshBuildInfo[World.WORLD_HEIGHT];
```

So, I went in to the debugger to see the exact value of the variable when the exception happened. Debugger output:

```
> meshes
Evaluation failed.
> 2+2
4
> meshes.Length
Evaluation failed.
> y
0
> position
{(-7168.5, -0.5, 4079.5)}
```

The index is 0, I can evaluation expressions just fine... except for the array that's not working. I can't get the length of it or its value.

I don't know how to solve this issue. What does "Evaluation Failed" mean? How can the index be out of bounds? Why is this only happening on OSX? How do I fix it?

`World.WORLD_HEIGHT` is a constant with a value of 16.

Comment: Which one is the line 226 in WorldController.cs?

Comment: Okokok, a though, maybe meshes.Length cannot be evaluated because it's null...?

Comment: I marked the line with a comment in the code I posted.

Comment: Well, meshes couldn't be evaluated either.

Comment: If meshses is not null (did you checked?) then the next step is to add the meshes.Length to a variable to see it in the debugger.

Comment: I added `Debug.Log(System.String.Format("Instantiating. meshes.Length={0}, meshes={1}", meshes.Length, meshes));` to the beginning of the function.  It gets printed just fine, the length is 16. The exception became a null reference at the same place the index out of bounds exception happened before. When I take that line out, it goes back to the index exception.

Comment: Whoa, that's really strange... just to try (i'm running out of ideas), instead of [y] as index can you put a [0] and try again?

Comment: This time the log shows this: `kernelErrorToOSStatus: OSStatus = -1 (error = 14)` repeated many times. Also, there was an IndexOutOfRange exception again, but on the next line (which accesses the exact same array). I set both indices to 0, so not sure how it got past one line but not the next. It happened when y=10, so it got through ten iterations before the error. Each time it was using an index of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of being frustrated by this issue, I've finally solved it (sort of). It only occurs when the game is built as x86_64 or Universal. Changing the architecture setting to x86 solved it. Must be a Unity bug.

Comment: I reported the bug, and got an email back confirming it is indeed a Unity bug and will be fixed in the next version.